# MISRA C 2012 rule 18.8 violation

Tags: c, misra

i got a MISRA C violation for the code bellow `

```
typedef enum NUMBER{
LOW = 0,
HIGH = 2 }NUMBER;

int main(void){
unsigned int A[HIGH]={2U,3U};}
```

what are the recommendations?

Best reds

Comment: Inventing your own private coding style is a horrible idea for a project with MISRA C quality concerns. Instead you should adopt a coding style commonly used by professional C programmers.

Answer (score 5):

- Rule 18.8 is about using VLA.
- An array using an enumeration constant is not a VLA. There is no VLA in your code.
- Conclusion: your static analyser is broken.